# Trying to get a cell to equal to a variable location

Tags: excel, vba

Ok noob at vba here. I am trying to update a cells formula on sheet 2 to equal to another cell on sheet 1. The location of the cell sheet can and will change. The only constant is the cell with "InsertC' in relation to the cell I need.

```
Range("O252").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sheet1!" & Cells.Find(What:="InsertC", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(-2, 8).Address
```

Current error is

> run time error '91' Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: That means the find was unsuccessful.

Comment: Side note: you want to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code. In this case `Range("O252").Formula = ...` would do the job just fine (if the find is successful)

Comment: `Cells.Find` will look on the ActiveSheet - if you want to look on some other sheet then you need to specify that explicitly.  eg `Sheet1.Cells.Find(...)`

Comment: Thank you for tips. They help me fix my formula to work just had to add sheets.cells you mention.

Answer (score 2):

You're cramming too many things into a single executable statement. Split. Things. Up.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet 'TODO: get the actual sheet you want to work with.

Dim searchResult As Range
Set searchResult = ws.Cells.Find(What:="InsertC", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'TODO: reconsider whether ActiveCell needs to be involved in the search.

If searchResult Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'couldn't find what we're looking for; bail out!

Dim offsetCell As Range
On Error Resume Next 'next instruction may raise an error - ignore it
Set offsetCell = searchResult.Offset(-2, 8)
If offsetCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'couldn't legally offset negative rows; bail out!
On Error GoTo 0 'resume raising runtime errors

ws.Range("O252").Formula = "=" & offsetCell.Address(External:=True)
```

Note the sheet's name doesn't need to be hard-coded in the formula - `offsetCell.Address`  can work it out for you if you specify `True` for the `External` parameter.

That will make the formula be e.g. `=[Book1]Sheet1!$A$1`, but the `[Book1]` part will be optimized away by Excel after the formula is successfully assigned.